# How do I append trien-label to trien-children?

Tags: scheme, racket

Write a function `(list-words T)` that consumes a Trie and returns a (listof Str) containing all the words in T, starting at the leftmost leaf.
I can't cant seem to figure it out

I tried using map and recursion:

```
(define-struct trien (label children))
;; a trie-node (TrieN) is a (make-trien Str (listof Trie))

;; a trie-node (TrieN) is a (make-trien Str (listof Trie))
;; a Trie is either:
;; a TrieN, or
;; a Str.

(define (list-words T)
  (cond [(not (trien? (trien-children T)))(if-string T)]
        [else (map list-words (trien-children T))]))



(define (if-string t)
   (cond [(empty? (trien-children t)) empty]
         [else (cons (string-append (trien-label t) 
                (first (trien-children t)))
                (if-string (make-trien (trien-label t) 
                (rest (trien-children t)))))]))
```

for example this test works (trien-children is a (listof Str):

```
 (list-words (make-trien "m" (list "at" "e" "y"))) -> (list "mat" "me" "my")
```

this does not work for this test because it's a listof **trien**

```
  (list-words (make-trien "z" 
              (list (make-trien "a" (list "ny" "p"))
                    (make-trien "e" (list "al" "ro" "st")) 
                    (make-trien "i" (list (make-trien "n" (list "c" "g")) 
                    (make-trien "p" (list "" "s")))) 
                    (make-trien "o" (list "ne" 
                          (make-trien "o" (list "" "m" "s")))))))
```

so my issue is getting it to work for a listof trien

Comment: What is 'trien'?

Comment: @ghosh: A trie-node.

Answer (score 1):

Use the design recipe!

The data definition is:

```
   ;; a Trie is either:
   ;;     a string
   ;;     a node, or

   ;; where a node is a
      (define-struct node (label children))

   ;; where label is a string
   ;;   and children is a list of Trie
```

This suggests that the structure of `words` should be:

```
   (define (words T)
     (cond
       [(string? T) ...]
       [(node? T)   ...]))
```

Now a trie consisting of a string contains only that word, so

```
   (words "foo")   ->  (list "foo")
```

Thus

```
(define (words T)
  (cond
    [(string? T) (list T)]
    [(node? T)   ...]))
```

If the trie T is a node consisting of a label and some children which are tries,
then  `(node-label T)` gives the label and `(trie-children T)` gives a list of tries.

```
   (define (words T)
     (cond
       [(string? T) (list T)]
       [(node? T)   ... (node-label T) ... (node-children T) ...]))
```

Now the elements of `(node-children T)` are tries, so `words` can be applied to them.

```
   (define (words T)
     (cond
       [(string? T) (list T)]
       [(node? T)   ... (node-label T) ... 
                        (map words (node-children T)) ...]))
```

Now using words on a single child gives a list of words. Using `(map words ...`) thus gives a list of list of words. To append these lists, we will use a helper function:

```
  (define (append-lists lists)
     (apply append lists))

   (define (words T)
     (cond
       [(string? T) (list T)]
       [(node? T)   ... (node-label T) ... 
                        (append-lists (map words (node-children T))) ...]))
```

The only question remaining is how to combine a label with the list of words represented by the children tries.